# Testing in python arround memoized functions

Tags: python, testing

I'm building a bunch of tests and discovered that some of them are failing when they are all run together. Looking at why they are breaking I discovered it is because we memoize some of the system calls for the setup.

Because I'm mocking the system calls and not the memoized the function is only computed once and so it leaks that information into the subsequent tests.

What is the elegant way to deal with memoized functions:

- Mock those instead of the system calls
- Create a parameter on the memoize to not work for tests
- Mock the memoize decorator to return the parameters
- Find where the data is memoized and clean it at the end of each test

Any other ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on a lot of details we can't know. If you want to disable _all_ memoization, then obviously the third version (mock the decorator) is the least work, and conceptually the cleanest. (And you can even mock the decorator to memoize between tests, which gives you the 4th one for free.) But if you only want to un-memoize a few specific functions, the first one obviously makes more sense.

Comment: More generally, this doesn't seem like a good fit for SO, because it's too vague and general to give a firm answer to, and because it practically begs for opinions and subjective discussion.

Comment: For this specific problem the easiest solution is just to take the memoize out because its being poorly used. I was just thinking has a general approach what would be a good solution. And why ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late but I found very easy to use `delete_memoized`:

```
# your function
@memoize(timeout=50)
def your_long_function():
    # do stuff

# your test
def test_get_folder_content_error_handled(self, flf):
    delete_memoized(your_long_function)
    your_long_function()
```

I just used this solution in Django (using [django-memoize](https://pythonhosted.org/django-memoize)) and it works like a charm!

Comment: I guess a bit too late :P

Comment: well it could be useful to someone, I hope

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MagicMock` instead of vanilla `Mock`.

Say your code is something like:

```
@memoize.Memoize()
def OAuthClient():
    """Returns an Oauth client."""
    return 'blah'
```

Mocking with `Mock` like this:

```
mymodule.OauthPasswordClient = mock.Mock()
```

Returns an error like this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'Mock'
```

But mocking with `MagicMock` like this:

```
mymodule.OauthPasswordClient = mock.MagicMock()
```

Works just fine.